# using ajax in zend to populate database in view

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework, populate

I'm using ZendFramework and I need to populate the data I store in database in a table in 
the view but I need to do that using Ajax and json
I have a web service that print the following

```
{"cat":[{"id":"1","name":"Meat","image_url":"meat.jpg"}, 
{"id":"2","name":"Soup","image_url":"soup.jpg"}, 
{"id":"3","name":"drink","image_url":"drink.jpg"}, 
{"id":"8","name":"Pastries","image_url":"Pastries.jpg"},
{"id":"9","name":"Ice-cream","image_url":"ice_cream.jpg"},
{"id":"10","name":"salad","image_url":"salad.jpg"}]}
```

the url for this web service is

```
http://localhost/resturant/public/categories/show-categories
```

how can I using this web service and Ajax populate the data  in Table
I'm so begineer in Ajax actually and I search google but still stuck
please  any Idea
thnxx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `$.getJSON` function:

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
```

To fill the table using `$.getJSON` as follows:

```
$.getJSON( "http://localhost/resturant/public/categories/show-categories", function(cat) {
   var categories = cat.cat;
   //Iterate throught the array
   for (var i=0;i<categories.length;i++)
   { 
     category = categories[i];
     //Append the category to the table using the format you want
     $("#mytable").append("<tr><td>"+category.id+"</td><td>"+category.name+"</td></tr>");
   }

})
```

Comment: when I write
alert(cat); it show the json string
but when I write alert(cat.cat) it shows undefined 
i also try 
alert(cat[0].cat)
and alert(cat.cat[0]) but also show undefined

Comment: It's because in my answer I should be using `$.getJSON` instead `$.get`. jQuery parses the response as an string instead parsing it as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I think that JS should not generate HTML (if it is possible). The good practice is to create `separated action`, that will be returns HTML. In this action you will call your API method, and in `View` you generate your table. IN JS you should only make an Ajax request to new action (and pass `dataType: 'html'` to ajax settings object).